# How Nuget copies files to the output directory when indirectly referenced by a project?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget, csproj

I tried to build a nuget package to copy some files to the output directory of the referenced project, and I did so as follows:

1. Create `[projectName].targets` file.
2. Use the `csproj` file to package the files to be copied with the `[projectName].targets` file.
3. Call `Copy` in the `[projectName].targets` file.

This works when the nuget package is referenced directly, but not when it is **referenced indirectly**, how can I solve this problem?